# Firebase reference on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to using Firebase on iOS. I have multiple view controllers that need access to the Firebase ref object. Is it okay for me to create a new ref instance for every view controllers? Does Firebase internally keep only 1 ref?

Another alternative is for me to create a singleton class with a Firebase instance as a member, then reuse in every VC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebase references](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_methods) are lightweight objects. The Firebase SDK keeps a single connection to the server that all references re-use. So you can keep many references without introducing network problems.